# Is there an easy way to get the ServerName in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, hostname

I have been searching for an easy way to get the ServerName of the machine where Symfony runs in Symfony (so that my app adapts when it is used on a host with a different ServerName), but I couldn't find one. I created a variable in app.yml and I fetch it, but I still wonder if there is no easier way to do this.
How are you doing this? I'm using Symfony 1.2 and 1.4 on different projects.

Comment: Can't you use gethostname()? http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php

Comment: Sorry, I do not want the hostname in fact, but the ServerName (I edited my post)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I think I found something :

```
$this->getRequest()->getHost()
```

This seems to work... It will work only if there is a request of course, so it is not universal. So, this won't work using CLI.

Comment: A colleague just told me that we should not rely on this, because there are many risks. He thinks the setting in YML file is the best solution...

Comment: could you elaborate on the risks please? :-)

Comment: There are at leas two situations where you do not want to rely on such a system : 
- when you do not use apache (when sending mails via a cronjob for instance)
- when you have several servers but you want to promote your site buy using only one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Not very nice, but I use `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` in my front controller file, and use that to determine the environment I'm activating:

```
$env = "prod";
if (preg_match("/qahost\.tld$/", $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]))
{
  $env = "qa";
}
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', $env, false);
sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();
```

I'd be interested to see the **proper** approach :-)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the same in controller. The following worked

```
public function login(Request $request): void
{
        $redirectUri = sprintf(
            '%s://%s%s',
            $request->getScheme(),
            $request->getHost(),
            $this->generateUrl('save-token'),
        );
}
```