# How to get the host name in symfony?

Tags: symfony1

if native php, i can do it like that: $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

what about in symfony?  what should I use?

Comment: the same way, they are called superglobals for a reason :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to get the ServerName in Symfony?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021228/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-the-servername-in-symfony)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sfAction class have a method called getHost(). I guess it's that you need, but you need to call it from an instance.

Comment: the sfWebRequest class has the method getHost(), not sfAction.