# How to generate the SERVER_NAME in a console with symfony?

Tags: symfony

I want to write a script that send notification mails to users and execute it every hour and I want it to match the server name that host the symfony site.  I've already tried with $_SERVER but it's not defined and the solution on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021228/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-the-servername-in-symfony) but there is no request with the console so it's does work.

Comment: Perhaps [gethostname](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symfony 5 Generating a URL from Console Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62283956/symfony-5-generating-a-url-from-console-command)

Comment: What do you mean by "generate"? Either you know which value to use (then set it), or you need another approach to determine it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no traditional 'web request/response' thing in console command, all URLs you generate with `{{ path('...') }}` in twig or `$this->generateUrl('...')` or similar controllers/services´, will be probably`http://localhost/...`

To fix that, simply add: (if you're on symfony 5.1+)

```yaml
# config/packages/routing.yaml
framework:
    router:
        # but you should move it to your .env file and user two differen env-variables for host and scheme
        default_uri: 'https://you-site-hostname.com/'
```

or if you are using older version, put
`router.request_context.scheme` and `router.request_context.host` to you parameters. Like

```yaml
# config/services.yaml
parameters:
    router.request_context.scheme: 'https'
    asset.request_context.host: 'you-site-hostname.com'
```

Take a look here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#generating-urls-in-commands

And here (my personal advice) https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/mailer/route-context